# Angularjs - Disabled context menu (click right mouse) depending of resolution

Tags: angularjs

I want to disabled context menu (click right mouse) depending of resolution.

This is my js code:

```
angularRoutingApp.controller('mainController', function($scope,$window) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        $(w).resize(function(){
            if (window.innerWidth<1024) {
// here i disabled the click right mouse
            }
        });
});
```

Any idea? thanks,

Comment: Disabling important browser functions are in almost any case bad decisions. Why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: because when the resolution is less that 1024px, i show a hidden message in tag body and hidden all page content, but if i do click right, i can to update the page and i see the content that i want to hide and lost my message.

Comment: Well, what stops your users from reloading the page with the browser reload button? Or reload by pressing cmd/ctrl+r? As I already said, this is a bad decision. Personally, I hate websites that cripple my user experience with such "hacks".

Comment: if the resolution is less that 1024 the page content hidden and shown a message, Is a internal web page, are the specifications.